# While wielding my first weapon set, will the gems from my second weapon set level up at the same rate?

Tags: path-of-exile

I think that *all* [gems receive 10% of each amount of EXP your gain](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Gem#Gem_Experience).  But on the same wiki's page, you can read:

> Gems gain experience and levels alongside the character **wearing** them.

And I've got the feeling that gems on my second weapon set (which I rarely use) don't level up as fast as the ones on my first weapon set...  Any clue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they should. You can read that from the same page you provided:

> **Gems equipped in both weapons slots gain experience**, though only the currently active weapon slot's skills can be used.

It's probably that the gems you're using on the second set happen to need more experience points to level up.

Comment: @Anto You're welcome. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Gems gain experience at the same rate (10%). What happens is that the abilities/gems equiped on the weapon/shield you are NOT currently using can't be used.

I.e in your inactive weapon you have a Hatred gem (cold aura), so you cannot cast it. If you cast it with such weapon active and then swap to the other weapon set, the aura uncasts.